# Divergence of transposed gradient of vector quantity

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I would appreciate some help with this.

Is:
$$
\nabla \cdot \left( \nabla \vec{v}\right)^T= \nabla \left( \nabla \cdot \vec{v}\right)
$$

How can I show this? Is the gradient of a vector mathematically defined?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer is incomplete, and it really illustrates why we need to take great care when using index notation. We first define the covariant derivative of a vector as well as the divergence of a matrix (in the standard basis):
$$(\nabla \boldsymbol u)^i{}_j=\partial_ju^i \\ (\nabla\cdot\mathbf M)_j=\partial_kM^k{}_j$$
Writing these out explicitly,
$$\nabla \boldsymbol{u} =\begin{bmatrix}
\partial _{1} u^{1} & \partial _{2} u^{1} & \partial _{3} u^{1}\\
\partial _{1} u^{2} & \partial _{2} u^{2} & \partial _{3} u^{2}\\
\partial _{1} u^{3} & \partial _{2} u^{3} & \partial _{3} u^{3}
\end{bmatrix} \\ \nabla\cdot\mathbf M=\begin{bmatrix}
 \begin{array}{l}
\partial _{1} M^{1}{}_{1}\\
+\partial _{2} M^{2}{}_{1}\\
+\partial _{3} M^{3}{}_{1}
\end{array} &  \begin{array}{l}
\partial _{1} M^{1}{}_{2}\\
+\partial _{2} M^{2}{}_{2}\\
+\partial _{3} M^{3}{}_{2}
\end{array} &  \begin{array}{l}
\partial _{1} M^{1}{}_{3}\\
+\partial _{2} M^{2}{}_{3}\\
+\partial _{3} M^{3}{}_{3}
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}$$
This means
$$\nabla \cdotp \nabla \boldsymbol{u} =\begin{bmatrix}
 \begin{array}{l}
\partial _{1} \partial _{1} u^{1}\\
+\partial _{2} \partial _{1} u^{2}\\
+\partial _{3} \partial _{1} u^{3}
\end{array} &  \begin{array}{l}
\partial _{1} \partial _{2} u^{1}\\
+\partial _{2} \partial _{2} u^{2}\\
+\partial _{3} \partial _{2} u^{3}
\end{array} &  \begin{array}{l}
\partial _{1} \partial _{3} u^{1}\\
+\partial _{2} \partial _{3} u^{2}\\
+\partial _{3} \partial _{3} u^{3}
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}$$
If we rearrange the terms a bit, we see that
$$\nabla \cdotp \nabla \boldsymbol{u} =\begin{bmatrix}
\partial _{1}\begin{pmatrix}
\partial _{1} u^{1}\\
+\partial _{2} u^{2}\\
+\partial _{3} u^{3}
\end{pmatrix} & \partial _{2}\begin{pmatrix}
\partial _{1} u^{1}\\
+\partial _{2} u^{2}\\
+\partial _{3} u^{3}
\end{pmatrix} & \partial _{3}\begin{pmatrix}
\partial _{1} u^{1}\\
+\partial _{2} u^{2}\\
+\partial _{3} u^{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Identifying $\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol u=\partial_1u^1+\partial_2u^2+\partial_3u^3$ this is
$$ \begin{array}{l}
\nabla \cdotp \nabla \boldsymbol{u} =\begin{bmatrix}
\partial _{1}( \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{u}) & \partial _{3}( \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{u}) & \partial _{3}( \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{u})
\end{bmatrix}\\
=\nabla ( \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{u})
\end{array}$$
On the other hand if we consider
$$( \nabla \boldsymbol{u})^{\intercal } =\begin{bmatrix}
\partial _{1} u^{1} & \partial _{1} u^{2} & \partial _{1} u^{3}\\
\partial _{2} u^{1} & \partial _{2} u^{2} & \partial _{2} u^{3}\\
\partial _{3} u^{1} & \partial _{3} u^{2} & \partial _{3} u^{3}
\end{bmatrix}$$
We see that
$$\nabla \cdot ( \nabla \boldsymbol{u})^{\intercal } =\begin{bmatrix}
 \begin{array}{l}
+\partial _{1} \partial _{1} u^{1}\\
+\partial _{2} \partial _{2} u^{1}\\
+\partial _{3} \partial _{3} u^{1}
\end{array} &  \begin{array}{l}
+\partial _{1} \partial _{1} u^{2}\\
+\partial _{2} \partial _{2} u^{2}\\
+\partial _{3} \partial _{3} u^{2}
\end{array} &  \begin{array}{l}
+\partial _{1} \partial _{1} u^{3}\\
+\partial _{2} \partial _{2} u^{3}\\
+\partial _{3} \partial _{3} u^{3}
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}$$
We can see readily that this is
$$ \begin{array}{l}
\nabla \cdot ( \nabla \boldsymbol{u})^{\intercal } =\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta \left( u^{1}\right) & \Delta \left( u^{2}\right) & \Delta \left( u^{3}\right)
\end{bmatrix}\\
=( \Delta \boldsymbol{u})^{\intercal }
\end{array}$$
It seems that Wikipedia has used the incorrect index order for the covariant derivative of a vector. They appear to think
$$(\nabla\boldsymbol u)^i{}_j=\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^i}$$
When in fact it should be the other way around. To be ultra clear, we need to specify how the covariant derivative and divergence work. Letting ${}^p_q\mathbb{R}$ be the space of $(p,q)$ tensors over $\mathbb{R}$, then
$$\nabla:{}^p_q\mathbb{R}\to{}^p_{q+1}\mathbb{R} \\ \operatorname{div}:{}^1_q\mathbb{R}\to {}_q\mathbb{R} \\ \Delta: {}^p_q\mathbb{R}\to {}^p_q\mathbb{R}$$
It is very important to distinguish between (column) vectors and covectors or row vectors.

---

I'll add one more thing to my answer to make it as complete as possible. Though in most fields in mathematical physics we try to write everything in covariant form, because of the divergence in the Navier-Stokes equations, it is actually more convenient to write everything in contravariant form. Typically you will see the N-S equations written in the general coordinate-free form
$$\rho\frac{\mathrm D\boldsymbol u}{\mathrm D t}=\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol \sigma+\rho\boldsymbol{a} \\ \text{along with the continuity equation} \\ \partial_t\rho+\nabla\cdot(\rho\boldsymbol u)=0$$
Both sides here have the units of force per unit volume. Let's expand this into coordinates. I will assume a general coordinate system to maintain the generality.
$$\rho\left(\partial_tu^i+u^j\nabla_ju^i\right)=\nabla_j\sigma^{ij}+\rho a^i$$
The components of the Cauchy stress tensor $\boldsymbol \sigma$ are ([see my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273528/is-there-a-consistent-formula-for-the-cauchy-stress-tensor-in-fluid-mechanics) )
$$\sigma^{ij}=(-p+\lambda \varepsilon^k{}_k)g^{ij}+2\mu\varepsilon^{ij}$$
Or, in coordinate free form,
$$\boldsymbol{\sigma}=(-p+\lambda \operatorname{tr}\boldsymbol\varepsilon)\mathbf{g}^{-1}+2\mu\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$$
$\lambda$ is the bulk viscosity. You'll notice that this formula is quite a bit different to the one on Wikipedia, and that's because this is about where Wikipedia begins to go very badly wrong. Instead of the inverse metric $\mathbf{g}^{-1}$ they have the identity tensor $\mathbf{I}$. Again, while in Cartesian coordinates they are one and the same, the distinction is very important when working in other coordinate systems.
Here $\boldsymbol\varepsilon$ is the rate-of-strain tensor, which we are defining contravariantly:
$$\varepsilon^{ij}=\frac{1}{2}\left((\nabla u)^{ij}+(\nabla u)^{ji}\right)$$
Where $(\nabla u)^{ij}$ is defined using an index raising, $(\nabla u)^{ij}=g^{jk}(\nabla u)^i{}_k$. One can see that $\boldsymbol \varepsilon$ is actually the *symmetric part* of the tensor $[(\nabla u)^{ij}]$. It is a easy exercise to check that
$$\operatorname{tr}\boldsymbol \varepsilon=\varepsilon^k{}_k=g_{kj}\varepsilon^{kj}=\operatorname{div}\boldsymbol u$$
And so in the case that $\boldsymbol u$ is incompressible, the Cauchy stress tensor reduces to
$$\boldsymbol\sigma=-p\mathbf{g}^{-1}+2\mu\boldsymbol\varepsilon \\ \sigma^{ij}=-pg^{ij}+2\mu\varepsilon^{ij}$$
Hence in this incompressible case
$$(\nabla\cdot \sigma)^i=\nabla_j\sigma^{ij}=-\nabla_jg^{ij}p+\mu\nabla_j\left((\nabla u)^{ij}+(\nabla u)^{ji}\right)$$
The first term, $\nabla_jg^{ij}p$ is just $\operatorname{grad}^i p$. The second term requires essentially the same computation from the previous part of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I would expect that $\nabla  \cdot \nabla \vec{v} $ would end up being the velocity Laplacian $\Delta \vec{v}$ and not $\nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec{v}$)

Comment: @Trailer The problem is that the Laplacian is supposed to maintain the shape of a tensor, however the operation $\nabla\cdot \nabla$ changes it's shape. This would of course be different if instead of the covariant derivative $\nabla$ one used its sharp $\operatorname{grad}^i=g^{ij}\nabla_j$ to make the operator $\operatorname{div}\circ \operatorname{grad}=\text{Lap}$. In Cartesian coordinates the distinction is unimportant, but when solving the N-S equations in e.g polar coordinates it matters.

Comment: @Trailer I've added some remarks on the Navier-Stokes equations that I think you will find useful.

Comment: Just to complement the last comment, $$\partial_i v_j = \nabla \mathbf{u} (u,v,w) =\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v }{\partial x}  & \frac{\partial w }{\partial x} \\\
\frac{\partial u }{\partial y} & \frac{\partial v }{\partial y} & \frac{\partial w }{\partial y}\\\
\frac{\partial u }{\partial z} & \frac{\partial v }{\partial z}  & \frac{\partial w }{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

One should use the covariant derivative here. It is defined generally for higher order tensors. (One may also define the gradient as the sharp of the covariant derivative). Letting $\nabla$ represent the covariant derivative, $\nabla \boldsymbol v$ is a $(1,1)$ tensor, or matrix. In the standard basis it has components
$$(\nabla \boldsymbol v)^i{}_j=\partial_jv^i$$
The divergence operator is also straightforward in these coordinates. To take the divergence of a vector,
$$\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol v=\partial_kv^k$$
Similarly for a matrix,
$$(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{M})_j=\partial_kM^k{}_j$$
Comparing the two expressions,
$$(\nabla\cdot\nabla \boldsymbol v)_j=\partial_k(\partial_jv^k)\\ \text{and} \\ (\nabla(\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol v))_j=\partial_j(\partial_kv^k)$$
Since partial derivatives commute, the two expressions are equal.

To show this is true in any coordinate system, more formalism is needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I had a typo ( was missing the transpose in the equation). But from your answer they should be equivalent, right?

Comment: @Trailer No, they are not equivalent. $(\nabla v)^i{}_j=\partial_j v^i$ whereas $((\nabla v)^\intercal)^i{}_j=\partial_iv^j$.

Comment: @Trailer What is the source of this equation?

Comment: Navier-stokes equations. The stress tensor is $\nabla \cdot \tau = \nabla \cdot [\eta ( \nabla\vec{v} +( \nabla \vec{v})^T)]$. Assuming $\eta$ to be constant, the expression will reduce to $\nabla \cdot [\eta ( \nabla\vec{v})]$ by assuming incompressibility ($\nabla \cdot \vec{v}=0$), thus the need for the above equation

Comment: @Trailer See my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273528/is-there-a-consistent-formula-for-the-cauchy-stress-tensor-in-fluid-mechanics) where we have written the Cauchy stress tensor $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ as the sum of a pressure part $-Pg_{ij}$ and the deviatoric stress tensor $\tau_{ij}=\mu((\nabla u)_{ij}+(\nabla u)_{ji})$

Comment: If you see here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations under the *incompressible* section and *Variational form of the incompressible Navier–Stokes equations* they will get the same relationship.

Comment: @Trailer Please have a look at my other answer for a more complete response.